# Why serialization of object that implements Serializable throws exception?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I'm trying to pass two ArrayLists via Intent to another activity. Created this class to store these two arrays.

```
public class StorageBin implements Serializable {
    //storage variables
    public ArrayList<String> placesList;
    public ArrayList<LatLng> latLngArrayList;

    public void storeData(ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<LatLng> locations) {
        placesList = names;
        latLngArrayList = locations;
    }
}
```

I am putting them into intent as follows.

```
            StorageBin storageBin = new StorageBin();
            storageBin.storeData(placesList, latLngArrayList);
            intent.putExtra("storedData", storageBin);
```

Last line causes following exception. What am I doing wrong?

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: lt.wilkas.isimintinosvietoves, PID: 24702
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
   serializable object (name = lt.wilkas.isimintinosvietoves.MainActivity$StorageBin)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1468)
   ...
```

Comment: `Serializable` doesn't actually guarantee serializability. You can easily write a class where `class MyClass implements Serializable { NonSerializableType field }`, and that compiles fine. And it *might* serialize, if `field` is null. Or if it's an instance of subclass of `NonSerializableType` which does implement `Serializable`.

Comment: `MainActivity$StorageBin` means that your `StorageBin` is nested inside the `MainActivity` class, but you didn't make the nested class `static`, so it's an *inner* class, which means that it is trying to serialize the entire `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that if my serializable class has an object inside which is not serializable, then my class becames unserializable too?

Comment: @wilkas correct. I think of `Serializable` as a marker that you intend a class to be serializable, rather than a guarantee that it will be; and the distinction between the two feels like a flaw in the design of Java's in-built serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect that it is because your `MainActivity` class is not serializable (either because it is not declared `Serializable`, or it has non-serializable field values), and `StorageBin` is an inner class (i.e. nested but not static).

Try making `StorageBin` static:

```
public static class StorageBin ...
```

The reason why not being static this breaks the serializability is that `StorageBin` has a hidden reference to `MainActivity`: this is what allows you to refer to instance methods on `MainActivity` (or `MainActivity.this`) in the body of `StorageBin`.

A lot of the time, this reference isn't necessary: not only does it break serialization, it can also cause memory leaks, because it prevents the `MainActivity` instance being garbage collected.

*Always* make your nested classes `static` unless they actually need to be otherwise.

---

If your use of the [`LatLng` class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) is also preventing serialization (since it does not implement `Serializable`), you have two choices:

- Stop using the `LatLng` class, and use a type which is serializable;

  - Either in your public API, so that `storeData` accepts a list of the other type
  - Make your public API appear to use `LatLng`, but then translate to a serializable type internally
- Mark the `latLngArrayList` field `transient`, and use `writeObject` and `readObject` to provide custom serialization and deserialization logic respectively.

  For example, you can serialize the coordinates to an array, and reconstruct the `LatLng` instances when you deserialize:

  ```
  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.defaultWriteObject();

    double[] coords = new double[2 * latLngArrayList.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (LatLng latLng : latLngArrayList) {
      coords[2*i+0] = latLng.latitude;
      coords[2*i+1] = latLng.longitude;
      ++i;
    }
    out.writeObject(coords);
  }

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in)
      throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    double[] coords = (double[]) in.readObject();
    // + Check that coords.length is even.
    latLngArrayList = new ArrayList<>(coords.size() / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < coords.size(); i += 2) {
      latLngArrayList.add(new LatLng(coords[i], coords[i+1]));
    }
  }
  ```

---

Note that implementing `Serializable` doesn't actually guarantee serializability. You can easily write a class:

```
class MyClass implements Serializable { NonSerializableType field }
```

and that compiles fine. And it *might* serialize, if `field` is null. Or if it's an instance of subclass of `NonSerializableType` which does implement `Serializable`.

I don't want to say that serialization is a guessing game, because it obviously works if used correctly; it's just hard to guarantee that you are using it correctly.

Comment: Doesn't the name `MainActivity$StorageBin` make your suspicion a certainty? ;-)

Comment: @Andreas not a certainty - how do you know that `MainActivity` isn't declared `Serializable` :)

Comment: I tried to add 'static' to the definition, but got the same error. After that tried to move this class outside of MainActivity class (also removing "public  static"), but then exception is as follows:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = lt.wilkas.isimintinosvietoves.StorageBin)
I think it may be associated with the class "LatLng", which is declared not by me.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. After removing array of LatLng objects, serialization works. This leaves me with question how do I pass this array to another activity :(

Comment: @ishmaelMakitl, your line allows me to put 'storageBin' into 'bundle', but as soon as I put bundle as intent extra, it gives me the same exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner, your suggestions regarding "static" and "nested class" were correct, but could you please update your answer, so it would mention why my code would still not work (reference to Google Maps 'LatLng' class), so I could accept it. Of course, you could give me a hint, how to pass this array of 'LatLng' objects to another intent as well :)